# How to SELECT a comma-separated string from a JSON_EXTRACT()-ed array in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, json

I have a MySQL 5.7 database table that stores a piece of information as JSON. The JSON structure for these records is something like this, stored in a column called, for instance `my_json`:

```
{
  "someString": "string",
  "someArray:": ["array", "of", "stuff"]
}
```

I can select the individual parts of this easily with a query like this:

```sql
SELECT mt.some_field AS some_field,
       JSON_EXTRACT(mt.my_json, "$.someString") AS some_string,
       JSON_EXTRACT(mt.my_json, "$.someArray") AS some_array
  FROM my_table AS mt
```

and I get a nice response with my JSON object split up into two separate columns.

What I would like to do though, is convert the JSON_EXTRACTed `someArray` property into a comma separated string.  So rather than a column called `some_array` with a value like `["array", "of", "stuff"]`, I want to have a column called `some_array` with a value like `array, of, stuff`.

Can anyone help me figure out the right SQL to do this?  (Again, using MySQL 5.7)

Thanks!!

Comment: Convert JSON to string and remove doublequotes and square brackets.

Comment: I linked this to a duplicate question, but honestly I would just return the JSON array to your app and decode the JSON there. It's bound to be easier.